# Transpile Async Await proposal with Babel.js?

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, ecmascript-next

There is a proposal for introducing C# style `async-await`. I know Babel.js transpiles ES6 to ES5, but is there any way to make it transpile async-await to `ES5`?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

### Babel v6

As of Babel v6, Babel doesn't contain any transformers itself anymore. You have to explicitly [specify any feature](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/) you want to transform.

#### Presets - non ES2015 environment

The quickest way to get this working is to use *presets* which already contain the set of plugins needed to transform ES2015 and newer proposals. For `async`, you will need the [`es2015`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) and [`es2017`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2017/) presets and the [`runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/) plugin (don't forget to install `babel-runtime` as described in the documentation):

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "es2017"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

#### Presets - ES2015 environment

If you run the code in an environment that supports ES2015 (more specifically, generators and Promises), then all you need is the es2017 preset:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2017"
  ]
}
```

#### Custom

To only transform the `async` functions, you will need the following plugins.

[`syntax-async-functions`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-async-functions/) is needed in any every case to be able to parse async functions

In order to *run* the async function, you either need to use

- [`transform-async-to-generator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/): Converts the `async` function into a generator. This will use Babel's own "co-routine" implementation.
- [`transform-async-to-module-method`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-module-method/): Also converts the `async` function to a generator, but passes it to the module and method specified in the configuration instead of Babel's own method. This allows you to use external libraries such as `bluebird`.

If your code runs in an environment that supports generators, then there is nothing left to do. However, if the target environment does *not* support generators, you will also have to transform the generator. This is done via the [`transform-regenerator`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/) transform. This transform depends on runtime functions, so you will also need Babel's [`transform-runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/) transform (+ the `babel-runtime` package).

#### Examples:

**Async to generator**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "transform-async-to-generator"
  ]
}
```

**Async to module method**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-async-functions",
   ["transform-async-to-module-method", {
     "module": "bluebird",
     "method": "coroutine"
   }]
  ]
}
```

**Async to generator + regenerator**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-async-functions",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-regenerator",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

---

### Babel v4 and older

Yes, you have to enable the [experimental transformers](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/). Babel uses [regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator).

> **Usage**
>
> ```
> $ babel --experimental
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> babel.transform("code", { experimental: true });
> ```

Comment: As the link suggests, you now have to set by stage or transformer: babel.transform("code", { optional: ["es7.asyncFunctions"] });

Comment: Your link to experimental transformers is broken.

Comment: Can you confirm @MattDell's answer below?

Comment: @Bergi: actually, it's different again with v6. Will update my answer later.

Comment: @Bergi Have a look at my answer below.

Comment: It took a long time to find this as the answer to "regeneratorRuntime is not defined". I wanted to avoid having to directly import/require any modules in my application, which most other answers were suggesting. Adding the "transform-runtime" plugin fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying the Async to module method (bluebird), but UglifyJS is choking on `function*`. How do we get rid of those? Is it even possible using this method?

Comment: @felix transform-async-to-generator is not necessary. transform-generator already handles it. http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/

Comment: After converting using "Async to generator + regenerator" I had an error "Unexpected token import". How to fix it?

Comment: @dantey89: ES6 `import` and `export` statements are not supported in any environment. You also have to configure Babel to convert that to CommonJS or whatever module system you are targeting.

Answer (score 6):

This solution may have changed since (Feb 25 Felix Kling) or perhaps there is still more than one way to use async await.

What worked for us was to run Babel like so

```
$ npm install babel-runtime
```

---

```
$ babel inputES7.js -o outputES5.js --optional runtime
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this working as-of today by doing an additional `npm install babel-preset-stage-0` and using it like

```
var babel = require("babel-core");
var transpiled = babel.transform(code, { "presets": ["stage-0"] });
```

See

- http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/#options
- http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps even more up-to-date now; just put the babel stuff in a separate file:

```
'use strict';

require('babel/register'); // Imports babel - auto transpiles the other stuff
require('./app'); // this is es6 - gets transpiled
```

See my code at [how-can-i-use-es2016-es7-async-await-in-my-acceptance-tests-for-a-koa-js-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369389/how-can-i-use-es2016-es7-async-await-in-my-acceptance-tests-for-a-koa-js-app) for some more details.

Answer (score 2):

The approved answer seems to be outdated now. The experimental flag has been deprecated in favor of stage.

http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/03/31/5.0.0/#experimental-option

> **Usage**
>
> ```
> $ babel --stage 0
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> babel.transform("code", { stage: 0 });
> ```

**Stage 0**

- es7.classProperties
- es7.comprehensions

**Stage 1**

- es7.asyncFunctions
- es7.decorators
- es7.exportExtensions
- es7.objectRestSpread

**Stage 2 (Stage 2 and above are enabled by default)**

- es7.exponentiationOperator

Comment: If I use `babel.transform(code, { stage: 0 }).code`, then I receive an `ReferenceError: [BABEL] unknown: Unknown option: base.stage` How do the options need to be set?

Comment: Hmm. Seemed to work for me when I set the above but looking at your answer it may have changed again.