# technical difference between ES7 async function and a promise?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I'm trying to understand better what an `async function` in JavaScript is technically, even if I basically know how to use them.

Many introductions to async/await make belive that an `async` function is basically just a promise, but that obviously is not the case (at least not with [Babel6-transpiled code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=async%20function%20asyncFunc%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20nop%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20fooPromise%20%3D%20new%20Promise%28r%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout%28r%2C%201%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.clear%28%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%22typeof%20asyncFunc%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20asyncFunc%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20function%0Aconsole.log%28%22typeof%20asyncFunc.next%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20asyncFunc.next%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0Aconsole.log%28%22typeof%20asyncFunc.then%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20asyncFunc.then%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%22typeof%20fooPromise%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20fooPromise%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20object%0Aconsole.log%28%22typeof%20fooPromise.next%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20fooPromise.next%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0Aconsole.log%28%22typeof%20fooPromise.then%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20fooPromise.then%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20function%0A%0A)):

```
async function asyncFunc() {
  // nop
}

var fooPromise = new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1));

console.clear();

console.log("typeof asyncFunc is", typeof asyncFunc); // function
console.log("typeof asyncFunc.next is", typeof asyncFunc.next); // undefined
console.log("typeof asyncFunc.then is", typeof asyncFunc.then); // undefined

console.log("typeof fooPromise is", typeof fooPromise); // object
console.log("typeof fooPromise.next is", typeof fooPromise.next); // undefined
console.log("typeof fooPromise.then is", typeof fooPromise.then); // function
```

Still, it is definitely possible to `await` a promise, like `await fooPromise()`.

- Is a `async funtion` a thing of it's own and `await` is simply *compatible* with promises?
- and, is there a way to distinguish between a simple `function` and an `async function` at runtime (in a Babel-compatible way)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An async function is a *function that returns a promise*. It helps you with cases where you have a bunch of asynchronous actions happening one after the other:

```
function asyncFunc() {
  return doSomethingAsync() // doSomethingAsync() returns a promise
    .then(() => {
      // do some stuff
      return doSomethingElseAsync(); // returns a promise
    })
    .then(something => {
      // do some stuff
      return doSomethingElseEntirelyAsync(something); // returns a promise
    });
}
```

Turns to

```
async function asyncFunc() {
  await doSomethingAsync(); // awaits for a promise
  // do some stuff
  let something = await doSomethingElseAsync(); // awaits for a promise
  // do some stuff
  return doSomethingElseEntirelyAsync(something); // returns the final promise
  // Note that even if you return a value, like return 5, the function as a whole
  // still returns a promise!
}
```

It reads a lot better, and you can use the normal tools like try/catch and for loops to work with them, even though they're async.

Async functions are **NOT** a replacement for promises, they're sugar on top of them, to handle specific cases where you have many sequential asynchronous actions.

Because `await` is basically just "await for this promise", you can still use the cool aggregation methods like `Promise.all()` and `Promise.race()` and await for the result of several (or the first of several) promises.

I'm not familiar with a way of distinguishing the two in runtime because, like classes, async functions are just sugar on top of Promises. (Although there might be hacks like using the function's `.toString` and parse the results, I don't count those).

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense. So, essentially, `asyncFunc` isn't a Promise, but `asyncFunc()` is - or with other words: `typeof asyncFunc().then == "function"`

Answer (score 0):

The couple `async/await` are a mechanism that let you write async code in an synchronous style and in my humble opinion it is the most simple and readable syntax so far to deal with asynchronous code (see also [this article](https://thomashunter.name/blog/the-long-road-to-asyncawait-in-javascript/)). The power of the syntax is really in how the `await` works. But in order to use `await` inside the body of a function, the function must have to be prefixed with `async`.

If you need more information there is a [spec for `async/await` here](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/).

The current implementation in Babel 5 is based on https://github.com/facebook/regenerator. As you can see in the [transpiled code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=async%20function%20asyncFunc(which%2C%20one%2C%20two)%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(which%20%3D%3D%3D%201)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20await%20one%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(which%20%3D%3D%3D%202)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20await%20two%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20asyncFuncMaybe(which%2C%20one%2C%20two)%20%7B%0A%20%20if(which%20%3D%3D%3D%201)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20one%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20if(which%20%3D%3D%3D%202)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20two%3B%0A%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20fooPromise%20%3D%20new%20Promise(r%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout(r%2C%201))%3B%0A%0Aconsole.clear()%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%22typeof%20asyncFunc%20is%22%2C%20%20typeof%20asyncFunc)%3B%20%2F%2F%20function%0Aconsole.log(%22typeof%20asyncFunc.next%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20asyncFunc.next)%3B%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0Aconsole.log(%22typeof%20asyncFunc.then%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20asyncFunc.then)%3B%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0A%0Aconsole.log(%22typeof%20fooPromise%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20fooPromise)%3B%20%2F%2F%20object%0Aconsole.log(%22typeof%20fooPromise.next%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20fooPromise.next)%3B%20%2F%2F%20undefined%0Aconsole.log(%22typeof%20fooPromise.then%20is%22%2C%20typeof%20fooPromise.then)%3B%20%2F%2F%20function%0A%0A) the function is compiled to:

```
function asyncFunc(which, one, two) {
  return regeneratorRuntime.async(function asyncFuncMaybe$(context$1$0) {
...
```

If you dig in Babel's `babel-regenerator-runtime` package you find Facebook's code. At [line 205](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/89d9db86488e61b7a5a3e00157d9544df424743e/packages/babel-regenerator-runtime/runtime.js#L205-L207) you find:

```
// Note that simple async functions are implemented on top of
// AsyncIterator objects; they just return a Promise for the value of
// the final result produced by the iterator.
runtime.async = function(innerFn, outerFn, self, tryLocsList) {
...
```

In order to transpile to ES5 the `async/await` Babel needs do to rearrange the code so we can keep track where we are during the execution of the function and the `AsyncIterator` is the object that keep track of that state.

Babel 6 gives you more options and let you choose the implementation that you want to use. See [Transpile Async Await proposal with Babel.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708975/transpile-es7-async-await-with-babel-js)

So regarding your questions:

- `async/await` are both a thing of it's own. According to the spec, they must work with promises. In particular you can `await` on a promise and when you execute an `async` function, it will return you a promise.
- Since an `async` function is transpiled to function that return a promise, there is not a straightforward way to distinguish it from a no-async function that return a promise.
  Your `fooPromise` should look more like `var fooPromiseFunc = function() {return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1))};` that make `fooPromiseFunc` and `asyncFunc` indistinguishable from a black box prospective. They are both functions that return a promise. What is the reason why you want to distinguish an `async` and no-async function at runtime? In practice they can be usedin the same way, so I do not see why you will have to threat them differently. For debug purposes if you really need to find out if a function is defined `async`, in Babel 5 you could use something like `(asyncFunc+"").indexOf('regeneratorRuntime.async') >
  0` or a more accurate regular expression. But that is really
  hacky and I would not use in a context outside of debugging or study.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. Re: *what is the reason why you want to distinguish an async and no-async function at runtime?*: actually I just wanted to distinguish normal callbacks from Promises (in the end to make `express` Promise/async-compatible in an automatic way). Now that I know how things work it's all clear to me and actually I was able to create a perfectly working (experimental) patch for `express`.

Comment: For that you may find these 2 links useful: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/ and https://github.com/luin/express-promise

Comment: Thanks for those links. I knew them already before posting this question and with help of the answers I found a way to avoid the use of a explicit wrapper function and still get exactly the same result.