# Compile asyn/await to es5 with babel js

Tags: javascript, babeljs, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

I have really small project with single .html file and one .js file. The problem that I used asyn/await functions so I need to convert it to es5 to be sure that everything works fine.

So, my .html file looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   ...//page markup

   <script src="dist/myCodeAsES5.js"></script>

   <script>
    var obj = new MyClass();
    obj.calculate();
   </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

And here my src.js

```
class MyClass{

    constructor(){
        this.calculate = async function () {
           await func1();
        }
    }

    async function func1() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         await func2(); // await in loop until func2() completed 
      }
    }

    async function func2() {
       for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         await func3(); //wait until func3 and then continue looping
       }
    }

    function func3() {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }


}
```

Now the main question- **how to convert it to es5** so it can be 100% woks in Internet Explorer. I had read a lot about "babel" but everything that I found is not understandable or out of date. 
So can somebody write a short step-by-step guide how to install and compile that  small project?

Comment: Did you read any documentation on the babel website? https://babeljs.io

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpile Async Await proposal with Babel.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28708975/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you want to quickly run a script to transpile your es5 code with babel follow these instructions:

- first thing you have todo is to setup a little node project.
  if you have never setup a node project goto:
  https://nodejs.org/en/download/
- as soon as you have npm globally you can goto your project folder and type:

  `npm init`

  this will create you a package.json file.
- goto: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation
  and click on `CLI` and follow all the mentioned steps.
- Make sure you install the correct presets for babel to transpile async await. You'll need the es2015 and stage3 preset and the runtime plugin.

  - `http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/#install`
  - `http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/#install`
  - `https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/#installation`
  - checkout [Transpile Async Await proposal with Babel.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708975/transpile-async-await-proposal-with-babel-js) for a more minimal setup.

Comment: Wouldn't the preset `es2017` make more sense than `stage-3`?

Comment: Ok, at least it clarifies me situation. But I can't get out of error after compiling "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Comment: @zeroflagL es2017 doens't contain async generator functions. http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-generator-functions/

Comment: That's because they are not part of ES 2017. And the question is not about them.

Comment: Funny, but I resolved this issue with rewriting code to TypeScript )))

Comment: @dantey89 can you help me with this task too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933983/converting-arrow-function-to-normal-js
Thanks