# How can I use async/await in my node v6.10.3 LTS code

Tags: node.js, async-await, ecmascript-next

I want to use async/await in my node v6.10.3 LTS code for AWS Lambda. However, from what I was reading, Node comes with bundles async/await support from v7.6.0.

How can I go about integrating async await in my code so that when the node version on lambda is upgraded, I would not have to make much(if any) changes.

Comment: Transpile your code with Babel?

Comment: Tbh I'm kind of a node beginner and don't have much idea about babel. Could you please explain a bit more? However, isn't transpilation for languages which run on browser? Node runs on V8

Comment: Babel takes some code and transforms it to equivalent code in a earlier version, such as ES2015 to ES5

Comment: Well, you can always just run the Babel CLI which transforms ES7/8 files to ES6 or ES5.

Comment: Yeah but why do I need to transpile Node ES6/7, when V8 can process it as it is? Transpilation is only needed because all browsers can understand ES6/7 right?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're targeting browser or Node... it just transforms files, so you can write code with async/await and transform it into ES6 code.

Comment: @Andrew Li, is async await a ES5 feature?

Comment: I want to convert MY ES6 promise based code to async await, I honestly fail to see how babel would help.

Comment: Wait, we're you suggesting using async await, transpiling before deploying to lambda?

Comment: Yes, to transpile then deploy if you want to use the feature.

Comment: Hmm, idk that'd be a bit more difficult to manage. Thanks for the idea though, will have to think about it.

Comment: The other option is of course to *not* use it and use promises instead (which are what they are under the hood)

Comment: @AndrewLi: *"It's ES7 AKA ES2016"* That's incorrect. `async/await` is going to be in this year's release, ES2017.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh? I could have sworn it was ES2016, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @AndrewLi: https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md

Comment: Have you seen the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708975/transpile-async-await-proposal-with-babel-js#28709165