# How to transform ES2017 to ES5

Tags: node.js, babeljs, ecmascript-2017, babel-polyfill

I have a es2017 code with async/await, I want to transform it to es5 so that it'll be supported by most Node.js versions.

My current .babelrc file looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017"]
}
```

So I'm transforming es2017 to es2016, from es2016 to es2015 and from es2015 to es5.

When I'm trying to run the code after I built it with `babel src -d dist -s` I'm getting error saying that: `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

How can I transform the es2017 code to es5? I wanna publish the code later and make it usable by node.js v4 and up.

Comment: You did the transformation just fine, you only need to add to the babel polyfill

Comment: @Bergi how do I use babel-polyfill if I'm building with babel-cli? I couldn't find that information anywhere

Comment: Related: [Transpile Async Await proposal with Babel.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708975/transpile-async-await-proposal-with-babel-js/28709165).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Bergi I found a way how to solve this `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` error.

I added the `transform-runtime` plugin to my .babelrc

Now my .babelrc is:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

There aren't any errors now and it works fine.